# How to solve a knapsack problem using a modified version of DP?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, discrete-mathematics

Im having difficulties understanding how to solve the knapsack problem using dynamic programming, where v is value and w is the weight, where I can fill up to a maximum weight j for some Capacity_J:

```
                               capacity_J
                          J_0   J_1  J_2   J_3  J_4  J_5  J_6
                            0     1    2    3    4    5    6  
 I_1    v(1) = 4, w(1) = 2  0     0    0    0    0    0    0 
 I_2    v(2) = 3, w(2) = 1  0     0    0    0    0    0    0 
 I_3    v(3) = 2, w(3) = 3  0     0    0    0    0    0    0 
 I_4    v(4) = 2, w(4) = 2  0     0    0    0    0    0    0
```

Using the following algorithm:

```
        for i = n . . . 1 do
                for j = 1 . . . k do
                      if w(i) ≤ j then
                        DP[i, j] := max(v(i) + DP[i + 1, j − w(i)], DP[i + 1, j])
                      else DP[i, j] := DP[i + 1, j];
        return DP[1, k]
```

Where DP is the recursive formula.

My understanding of that is:

I start with `i = n = I_4`

For `j = 1 = J_1` I check `if w(i) ≤ j -> 2 ≤ 0` so I go to `DP[i, j] = DP[4 + 1, 1]` which does not make much sense for me since `max(I) = 4`

My confusion comes from the fact that most explanations on that topic uses  different version of the knapsack algortihm:

```
    for i from 1 to n do:
        for j from 0 to k do:
            if w[i] > j then:
               DP[i, j] := DP[i-1, j]
            else:
               DP[i, j] := max(DP[i-1, j], DP[i-1, j-w[i]] + v[i])
```

Resulting in:

```
                                 capacity_J
                          J_0   J_1  J_2   J_3  J_4  J_5  J_6
                            0     1    2    3    4    5    6  
 I_1    v(1) = 4, w(1) = 2  0     0    4    4    4    4    4 
 I_2    v(2) = 3, w(2) = 1  0     3    4    7    7    7    7 
 I_3    v(3) = 2, w(3) = 3  0     3    4    7    7    7    9 
 I_4    v(4) = 2, w(4) = 2  0     3    4    7    7    9    9
```

However, I suppose if using the first version of the knackpack algortihm the direction of the movement is changing regarding the starting and ending position.

Appreciate if someone could provide examples of some iterations for the first algorithm.